# Transform foregin key number into two fields from related table

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

Last few days I was doing some SQL connected with ASP.NET stuff and whole the time I was trying to avoid making a long queries and preffered to make two/three shorter. But now I have to make it in long query, but have no idea how.

I have two tables: **person (idperson, name, surname)** and **visit (id, time, idperson)** and what I want to do is to display on website with GridView **time, name and surname** of person, based on relations. Normal GridView puts time and idperson.

Simply I want to replace idperson in visit table with name and surname from person table. I know how to do that in SQL but when it comes to ASP.NET and GridView... I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SELECT Command of the SqlDataSource you should make a join. For example you can use the following:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT visit.time, person.name, person.surname FROM person
LEFT JOIN visit ON person.idperson=visit.idperson"
```

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I have changed LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN and it looks just like I wanted. Now, I see that commands that I can put in Grid View are almost the same as normal mssql queries, thanks :)

Comment: Found one problem here. Edit and Cancel functions doesn't work at all, they are working just like refresh

Comment: How is your gridview code look like? Are you using boundfields? Are you using TemplateFields?

Comment: Yes, I am using boundfields and also TemplateFields because I wanted to allow to change only date of visit so others I replaced with Label instead TextBox

Comment: Have a look to this GridView example from MSDN. It will solve all of your questions about the GridView. Apparently you are making somewhere in your code a mistake, but I cannot locate it without seeing your code. The link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx